# Classify data (cell array) based on years in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, cell-array

Suppose that we have this cell array of data :

```
a={43 432 2006;
254 12 2008;
65 35 2000;
64 34 2000;
23 23 2006;
64 2 2010;
32 5 2006;
22 2 2010}
```

Last column of this cell array is years. I want classify data(rows) based on years like this :

```
a_2006 = {43 432 2006;
32 5 2006;
32 5 2006}

a_2008 = {254 12 2008};

a_2000 = {65 35 2000;
64 34 2000}

a_2010 = {64 2 2010;
22 2 2010}
```

I have different years in column three in every cell array (this cell array is a sample) so I want an automatic method to determine the years and classify them to `a_yearA` , `a_yearB` etc. or other naming that I can distinguish years and call data with years easily in following codes.

How can I do this?

Thanks.da

Comment: So is it my understanding that you would like MATLAB code that will separate the one cell array into multiple cell arrays that have those variable names?

Comment: Yes. It is a sample naming. Maybe we can find other naming because I want call every new cell array by years easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eval is not recommanded here. I would suggest to save it in a struct array like that

```
a={43 432 2006;
254 12 2008;
65 35 2000;
64 34 2000;
23 23 2006;
64 2 2010;
32 5 2006;
22 2 2010};

tmp = cell2mat(a);
% clear a or take another variable name for your struct to prevent warnings
clear a 
years=unique(tmp(:,3));
for n = 1:numel(years)
    a.(['a_' num2str(years(n))])=tmp(tmp(:,3)==years(n),:);
end
```

looks like that

```
>> a

a = 

    a_2000: [2x3 double]
    a_2006: [3x3 double]
    a_2008: [254 12 2008]
    a_2010: [2x3 double]

>> a.a_2000

ans =

          65          35        2000
          64          34        2000
```

Furthermore, you can easily access your struct arrays in a loop again (what you can't do such easy with the eval hack).

```
>> names=fieldnames(a)

names = 

    'a_2000'
    'a_2006'
    'a_2008'
    'a_2010'

>> for n = 1:numel(names)
    a.(names{n})
end
```

## update with strings in cell

Well, say there are strings in your cell

```
a={'43' '432' 2006;
'254' '12' 2008;
'65' '35' 2000;
'64' '34' 2000;
'23' '23' 2006;
'64' '2' 2010;
'32' '5' 2006;
'22' '2' 2010};

% save original variable 'a' for accessing later
tmp.cell = a;

% save just the years in a matrix for more easy accessing + we need the
% indizes for getting the values from the cell later in the loop
tmp.years = cell2mat(a(:,3));

% clear variable a or take another variable name for your struct to prevent warnings
clear a 

% get unique years for iteration
tmp.unique_years=unique(tmp.years);

for n = 1:numel(tmp.unique_years)
    a.(['a_' num2str(tmp.unique_years(n))])=tmp.cell(tmp.years==tmp.unique_years(n),:);
end
```

The result is the same, but your structs are now cells

```
>> a

a = 

    a_2000: {2x3 cell}
    a_2006: {3x3 cell}
    a_2008: {'254'  '12'  [2008]}
    a_2010: {2x3 cell}
```

Comment: Good use on using a structure.

Comment: That's good but in some cases I have strings in `column 1` or `column 2` so I can't use something like `cell2mat`. I think you can edit this answer with these informations.

Comment: @user2991243 - Why don't you include all of the information so that we aren't second guessing ourselves?  I didn't know that some values in the third columns are strings.  In that case, my approach is completely invalid.

Comment: You're right. We don't have string in column three. In some cases we have string in column 1 and column 2. Your answer was right and I changed some parts in above answer. It worked. Thanks.

Comment: I've added a very similar solution for the case, that you've got strings in your cell. In that case, you've got a small overhead, because you need the row indizes of the years. Thats the reason you need `tmp.years` and `tmp.unique_years`.
when column 3 are strings too, then you need a `str2double` instead of `cell2mat` for `tmp.years`.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this quite easily using [`eval`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html).  What you do is first determine the unique years in the third column.  You then iterate over these years, find those rows that share this same year, then use `eval` to extract these cell arrays for you and place them as new variables.  How `eval` works is that it takes in a command you want to execute as a **string**.  This is perfect if we want to dynamically run different commands based on some input, which in your case is creating different variable names.  As such, try doing this, assuming `a` is the created cell array you specified:

```
yearColumn = [a{:,3}];
years = unique(yearColumn);
for year = years
    ind = find(year == yearColumn);
    eval(['a_' num2str(year) ' = a([' num2str(ind) '],:);']);
end
```

Doing the above statement thus gives me the following cell arrays:

```
a_2000 = 

[65]    [35]    [2000]
[64]    [34]    [2000]


a_2006 = 

[43]    [432]    [2006]
[23]    [ 23]    [2006]
[32]    [  5]    [2006]


a_2008 = 

[254]    [12]    [2008]


a_2010 = 

[64]    [2]    [2010]
[22]    [2]    [2010]
```

---

Based on your comments, you would like to use a [`containers.Map`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map-class.html), which is what is known as an [**associative array**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).  In Python, these are also called [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping).  What you do is you specify a **key**, and what is produced is a **value**.  As such, we can use the years as **keys**, and the values that are produced are the **cell arrays** themselves.  As such, we can simply modify the above code to make use of a `containers.Map` like so:

```
yearColumn = [a{:,3}];
yearArray = containers.Map('KeyType', 'double', 'ValueType', 'any');
years = unique(yearColumn);
for year = years
    yearArray(year) = a(year == yearColumn,:);
end
```

You can then access your years using the year like so:

```
yearArray(2000)

ans = 

[65]    [35]    [2000]
[64]    [34]    [2000]

yearArray(2006)

ans = 

[43]    [432]    [2006]
[23]    [ 23]    [2006]
[32]    [  5]    [2006]

yearArray(2008)

ans = 

[254]    [12]    [2008]

yearArray(2010)

ans = 

[64]    [2]    [2010]
[22]    [2]    [2010]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why when I remove `'a_'` to only have years as output (naming) It returns an error like this ? : `Error: The expression to the left of the equals sign
is not a valid target for an assignment.` How can I solve this?

Comment: You need the `a` in there because if you remove it, you would be assigning to a variable that is purely a number, and MATLAB does not allow that.  For example, try doing `a_2000 = 3;` in MATLAB, then try doing `2000 = 3;`.

Comment: This is beyond my question but if we want only years for naming how we can do this?

Comment: Simply put, you can't.  What you **could** do is put this into a `containers.Map`, and access the year that way.  As such, it would be something like this `a[2000]`, and then you'd access your cell array contents that way.  Is this something you want?  I can easily modify my answer to use a `containers.Map`.

Comment: Please add this method (using `containers.Map`). I think this idea will complete the asnwer. Thanks again.

Comment: @user2991243 - Done.  Good luck!